# can request querystring be accessed from htmlhelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Hi
Can query string be accessed in HTMLHelper extension methods. We need to render differently depending on the querystring in the request.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Yes, through the current context, which is a property on HTML Helper.

```
public static string DoThis(this HtmlHelper helper)
{
   string qs = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("val");
   //do something on it
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Sure:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Foo(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
{
    var value = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request["paramName"];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can access the querystring via the HttpContext object. Like so...

```
string itemVal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["item"];
```

Comment: NOTE: `HttpContext.Current` should be avoided in ASP.NET Core where possible