# Using Request.QueryString inside C# View Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to write a View Helper that will know about the parameters in the URL, but I cannot get access to the Request.QueryString:

```
    public static MvcHtmlString SortDirectionArrow(this HtmlHelper html, string column)
    {
        string desc = Request.QueryString["desc"].ToString();
        string currentSortedColumn = Request.QueryString["sort"].ToString();

        if (desc == "False" && currentSortedColumn == column)
        {
            return new MvcHtmlString("desc");
        }
        else{
            return new MvcHtmlString("");
        }
    }
```

And you can't just create a new version of HTTPRequestBase because it's an interface:

```
        HttpRequest Request = new HttpRequest(); // or            
        HttpRequestBase Request = new HttpRequestBase();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
var desc = html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("desc");
```

Found this on [can request querystring be accessed from htmlhelper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4145111/can-request-querystring-be-accessed-from-htmlhelper)

Comment: Thanks! So "this" is giving me the access to the View stuff... I just didn't know I had to drill down so far through the object. any reasons for the loose type of var?

Comment: Even I didnt knew it. So thanks. My googling skills helping both ;) Talking about var it allow anonymous types, its called lazy coding

Comment: var isn't loose typed, it is just inferred. From the compiler point of view it is no different to saying explicitly what the type is - its just down to personal preference or whatever code style guideline you are following.

Comment: and `this` in the method declaration is just saying that it is an extension method and that the first parameter is what it is extending and can thus be omitted when calling it like this. it doesn't make any difference to what properties, etc. are available on `html`, it just effects the calling syntax.